# Any better way to use if else statement while using an “using” block statement?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, operators, instance

I have a scenario where I have two new objects in which only one has to be initialized according to the condition.

But I am using the “using” block statement for initializing a new object.

How can I achieve it? Please refer the below scenario.

```
int a;
string b;

if()//some codition
{
    using(MyClass c1 = new MyClass(a))
    { 
            SomeMethod();
    }
}
else
{
    using(MyClass c1 = new MyClass(b)
    {
             SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve this in single condition or any other way to reduce the code? because I am calling the same method in both condition.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anish

Comment: what is your `if condition` ?

Comment: You can `using(MyClass c1 = new MyClass(condition ? a : b))`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria `a` and `b` are different types, so the ternary operator won't compile against those directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Conditional (Ternary) Operator.

```
int a;
string b;

using(MyClass c1 = (some condition) ? new MyClass(a) : new MyClass(b))
{
    SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: It's called a conditional ternary operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: +1 for being the only one to spot that `a` and `b` are different types so can't satisfy the ternary operator on their own.

Comment: @john - no, it's called the conditional operator. *Some* people choose to call it ternary because *most* languages only contain one ternary operator and it's the conditional operator.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oddly enough I call it the ternary operator but I have no prior experience with it from other languages lol, I must've just cottoned on to someone else calling it that for that very reason.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've updated my comment as per MSDN :) I was attempting to change it from "ternary if", but failed with my edit slightly.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
using (var c1 = condition ? new MyClass(a) : new MyClass(b))
{
    SomeMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any better way to achieve this in single condition or any other way to reduce the code?

Yes, you can.

```
using (MyClass c1 = condition ? new MyClass(a) : new MyClass(b))
{
    SomeMethod();
}
```

`?:` is a Ternary operator which as the name suggests, works on 3 operands.

Answer (score 1):

```
  IDisposable target = somecondition ?  new MyClass(a)  : new MyClass(b) ;
  using (IDisposable c1 = target )
  {
                SomeMethod();
  }
```

Comment: a and b are of different type.